# Android-How to close progress dialog when back button is pressed

Tags: android

How to close progress dialog when back button is pressed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
       dialog.dismiss();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

or also you can dismiss dialog in onPause method of activity.

Answer (score 46):

A much better way.

```
          ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
          dialog.setCancelable(true);
          dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
             @Override
             public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog){
                /****cleanup code****/
          }});
```

The `setCancelable` method tells the ProgressDialog to close when the back button is pressed.  The listener at the end allows you to do anything that may need to be done as a result of a cancel (like closing a socket).

Comment: what is the reverse of this method? If the back button was pressed, I don't want my dialog to be closed.

Comment: @DeeV  Is it possible to make ProgressDialog setCancelable(false) and when user press back button it should dismiss progressDialog and go to previous activity.

Comment: @Nav The easiest way to do that would be to implement a cancelable dialog, then in the `onCancelListener()` call `finish()`.  The dialog will close, and the Activity will end.

Comment: this also cancels the dialog box if user clicks anywhere else on the screen (not necessarily the back button). how to prevent that. how to just cancel only when back button pressed?

Comment: @AbhinavRaja There's a method called `#setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean)` which you can use to prevent that.

Comment: @DeeV thanks for your help there! That was really helpful. But is there a way in which my real toolbar's back button(home button) can also be detected? Currently, my entire toolbar is also considered as a "touchOutside".

Comment: @Sid: Not from what I know.  Dialogs are their own window on top of the Activity Window so the "touch outside" area is everything that's not the dialog itself.

Comment: Good answer :) Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Well i found my approach much more useful. if you set progressDialog.setCancelable(true); it will cancel the dialog if the user would press anywhere on the screen outside the dialog. You wouldn't want that, right?  If you want the progress dialog to cancel only if the user presses the back button then use this code:

```
ProgressDialog pDialog;

pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this) {
             @Override
                public void onBackPressed() {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }};
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading");
         pDialog.setCancelable(false);

         pDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 3):

I would honestly just do:

The Dialog interface provides a ***dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)*** method which enables precisely this. You call that with a false value and the user won't be able to press the back button to go back to your activity

Answer (score 2):

By default `progress dialog` get `dismiss`, if you click on `back button`. Or, you can add this line:

`progress.setCancelable(true);`

Another option is you can call `finish()` and then `progress.dismiss()`:

```
progress.setOnKeyListener(new ProgressDialog.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface arg0, int keyCode,
                KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                finish();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            return true;
        }
});
```

Or, you `override` method `onCancel()` method in `back key` pressed `button event`.

Comment: worked for me thanks a lot ...it prevented my double click ....divya

Answer (score 1):

```
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ActivityName.this, 
                                    "Title","Message");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Do something...
        }
    });
```

When you press the back button, `onCancel` is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(yourActivity.this);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
.
.
.
progressDialog.show();
```

Hope, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple just copy the below code and paste within Async..

```
ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this) {
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            dialog.cancel();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    };
    // dialog.setTitle("file is..");//its optional If u want set title in progress
    // bar
    dialog.setMessage("Loading....");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution:

```
Dialog dialog;
dialog = new Dialog(context,style);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dismiss dialog in onPause method of activity. 
Here is the solution. It worked in case of me.

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Make sure `private ProgressDialog progressDialog;` declared globally

and initialize `progressDialog` on `onCreate` method just like this:

`progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivityGoesHere.this);`

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(yourActivity.this);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
.
.
.
progressDialog.show();
```

works very fine